# Is ALLOW_INVALID_DATES necessary to input past and future dates?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm looking at the MySQL documentation ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates)) and was wondering whether or not `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` is necessary to input past and future dates for the datatype `DATE`?

The documentation has this to say about it:

> ALLOW_INVALID_DATES
>
> Do not perform full checking of dates. Check only that the month is in the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31. This may be useful for Web applications that obtain year, month, and day in three different fields and store exactly what the user inserted, without date validation. This mode applies to DATE and DATETIME columns. It does not apply TIMESTAMP columns, which always require a valid date.
>
> With ALLOW_INVALID_DATES enabled, the server requires that month and day values be legal, and not merely in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode disabled, invalid dates such as '2004-04-31' are converted to '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. With strict mode enabled, invalid dates generate an error. To permit such dates, enable ALLOW_INVALID_DATES.

So if `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` was disabled, would dates that aren't the current date (past and future dates) be converted to '0000-00-00'?

Or does it mean that padded months and days (`2018-01-12` or `2018-11-01`, etc) will be converted?

Or only dates that are completely invalid such as `2018-13-01` or `2018-12-33`?

Comment: @Strawberry explanation??

Comment: Sorry, option 3 is correct- but rather than ask us, why not test this for yourself?

Comment: @Strawberry i don't have an easy way to test it. i'm gon be inputting the data from a python script and i'm a python n00b and don't have mysql installed locally. i also have no idea how to enable or disable `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` via phpmyadmin or whatever lol :/

Comment: @Strawberry for clarity's sake, `2018-01-08` would be accepted by MySQL while `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` is disabled, correct?

Comment: 2018-01-08 is not an invalid date, so I don't see how it clarifies anything

Comment: @Strawberry clarification regarding your previous comments.

Comment: I would encourage you to 'install' MySQL locally. I have it on a tiny usb stick plugged into the side of my monitor.

Comment: @Strawberry i definitely should. i should've ages ago. for some reason i'm just intimidated running things like MySQL, node, etc locally

Comment: View "invalid" as "impossible".  Past and future are not impossible, month #14 is.

Comment: @Nic3500 kk thx